# MYSQL how to retrieve relevant values of two foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have a master table of users with some basic structure as

**Users**

---

userId | userName | userJoinedOn

---

159 | Alex  | 2015-08-23

160 | Steve | 2015-08-23

161 | Rocky | 2015-08-23

A user transactions table is as follows. Here user1 and user2 are foreign keys to users table.

**UserTransactions**

---

user1 | user2 | transaction

---

159 | 160 | 3

159 | 161 | 2

160 | 159 | 2

160 | 161 | 2

161 | 159 | 2

161 | 160 | 2

I want to retrieve the above transaction as follows:

user1Id | user1Name | user2Id | user2Name | transaction

---

159 | Alex | 160 | Steve | 3

Also, can it be further narrowed down to two users who have performed the same transaction with each other.
Like 160 and 161 have both done transaction 2 with each other.

I am assuming this is going to be pretty resource intensive for the servers with large number of users.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join 2 tables:

```
SELECT
    u1.userId as user1Id,
    u1.userName as user1Name,
    u2.userId as user2Id,
    u2.userName as user2Name,
    ut.transaction
FROM
    UserTransactions ut
        INNER JOIN Users u1 ON (ut.user1 = u1.userId)
        INNER JOIN Users u2 ON (ut.user2 = u2.userId)
```

An `SQL JOIN` clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them.

The most common type of join is SQL INNER JOIN. An SQL `INNER JOIN` return all rows from multiple tables where the join condition is met.

`user1` column in the `UserTransactions` table refers to the `userId` in the `Users` table. `user2` column in the `UserTransactions` table refers to the `userId` in the `Users` table. So we must join `UserTransactions` with `Users` table twice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. +1 for nicely formatting it. Would have loved if some explanation was there too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins:

```
select ut.User1Id, u1.userName, ut.User2Id, u2.userName, ut.transaction
from UserTransactions ut left join
     Users u1
     on ut.user1Id = u1.userid left join
     Users u2
     on ut.user2Id = u2.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the users table twice with alias:

```
select user1.userId , user1.username ,user2.userId , user2.username, transaction
from usertransaction join users user1 on user1=users.userid
join users user2 on user2=users.userid
```